# How to retrieve values from multiple forms at once

Tags: javascript, python, django

So I am using dropzone js to create drag and drop file upload forms with django. Dropzone requires that you use a django form with a class of dropzone, since I am also allowing users to put in text, I just went ahead and created two forms with django. One for dropzone drag and drop file uploader and one for the normal input field. I created a submit button that submits both forms simultaneously when the button is clicked, did this with javascript. I've been trying to retrieve information from the submitted forms but keep getting None returned even though I submitted something. Any idea why?

```
  <button type="submit" id="add">Save</button>
  <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6" id="inner">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inputform" name="form1">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <input type="text" name="product_title" id="product_title" placeholder="Give your product a name">
        <h4>Price</h4>
        <input type="text" name="product_price" id="product_price" placeholder="0.00">
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <input type="text" name="product_description" id="product_description" placeholder="Write a description about your product">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6" id="inner2">
      <h3>Images</h3>
      <form method="POST"  action="#" class="dropzone col-sm-8 col-lg-8" id="dropzone" name="form2">
        {% csrf_token %}
      </form>



def add(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      print(request.POST.get("product_title"))
  return render(request,"main/add.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think submitting a form will reload the page. 
No matter how many forms you have in a page, just a single submitting form will reload page and there will be no way for submitting other forms.

If you want to submit multiple forms without data loss, I think you should use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).